# Changing content outside of bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am creating a web page that displays a series of product images using a bootstrap carousel. Under the carousel there is a description of each product. (Se picture)

[image]

What would be the cleanest way to change the content section, to fade in and out, without wrapping the whole thing inside of the "carousel-inner" wrapper?

Code example:

```
<div id="product-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#product-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <!-- X number of items-->
    <li data-target="#product-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <section id = "section-intro-image" style = "background-image: url(url-to-image);">
            <h1>Product name</h1>
        </section>
    </div>
    <!-- X number of items-->
    <div class="item">
        <section id = "section-intro-image" style = "background-image: url(url-to-image);">
            <h1>Product name</h1>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#product-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#product-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
<!-- X number of content divs-->
<div class="content">
    <!--Change this contentdiv when the carousel changes-->
<h1>Product name</h1>
<p>
        Some content
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) functions to append new content to an element.

e.g.:

```
$('#section-intro-image').empty().append('<p>Whatever you like...</p>');
```